# iOS sdk question: how do I cast a UIView to a UIImage View (alternativly how do I get a UIImageView from a GestureRecognzer?)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

Desired end result: user taps a UIImageView and the image changes to another image (a subsequent tap returns the image to the original state)

Problem: I add a (unique) selector to a bunch of UIImageViews (in an array) and point the action at the same function - let's call this function imageTapped: for now.  Here is my code so far:

```
-(void)imageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture {
    UIImageView *view = tapGesture.view;
    // rest of code...
}
```

This code actually works fine but gets a warning when I run it: "Incompatible objective c types initilizing 'struct UIView *', expected 'struct UIImageView *'

Any way to get rid of this?  Not sure how casting works in objective c... primitive types seem to work fine such as (int)someFloat works fine but (UIImageView)someUiView doesn't work.  Like I said, code works alright when I run it but would like to get ride of the compiler warning.  Any help would be awesome.... I am very new to objective c (or any non java language for that matter) so be gentle.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your local variable "view" is a pointer to a UIImageView so cast it that way:

```
UIImageView *view = (UIImageView *)tapGesture.view;
```

Don't forget the asterisk in the cast.

Comment: oh wow, worked like a charm.  Thanks. Like I said new to pointers so didn't even think about that.

Comment: user439299, welcome to SO.  Please make sure to accept his answer then if it solved the issue!

Answer (score 1):

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
[self.view setIsAccessibilityElement:YES];
[scrollView1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
scrollView1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
scrollView1.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
scrollView1.clipsToBounds = YES;        // default is NO, we want to restrict drawing within our scrollview
scrollView1.scrollEnabled = YES;
NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundleRoot error:nil];
onlyPngs = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.png'"]];
arrPngs = [onlyPngs mutableCopy];
// load all the images from our bundle and add them to the scroll view
kNumImages = [onlyPngs count];
NSInteger index;
for (index = 0; index <kNumImages; index++)
{
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithString:[onlyPngs objectAtIndex:index]];
    if ([[imageName substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString: [[imageName substringToIndex:1] capitalizedString]]){
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
     UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
     // setup each frame to a default height and width, it will be properly placed when we call "updateScrollList"
     CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
     rect.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;
     rect.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;
     imageView.frame = rect;
     imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
     imageView.tag = index;// tag our images for later use when we place them in serial fashion
     imageView.accessibilityLabel = @"help";
     UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
     [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
     [tap release];
     [scrollView1 addSubview:imageView];
     [imageView release];
    }    
}
[self layoutScrollImages];
 }
-(void)imageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture{
UIImageView *view = (UIImageView *)tapGesture.view;
NSInteger  i=view.tag;
id iname =  [[self arrPngs] objectAtIndex:i];
NSLog(@"tag = %i %@",i,iname);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For any casting from any UIController to your view, where `Yourview` is the view that you want to cast:

```
Yourview *yourView=(castYourview *)uivontroller.view
```